# Junit test suite execution programmatically

Tags: java, junit4

I want to build a tool in java, where I can see the progress of my Junit test suite execution. Like below.

1. Current executing class.
2. How many test cases completed(Passed, Failed)?
3. How many test cases pending?

From this information, I want to build a graphical report.

How to start?

Comment: There are open source tools that already do that for you. Are you trying to reinvent the wheel or just want to roll your own?

Comment: Like an Eclipse for example

Answer (score 4):

The preferred external facade seems to be [JUnitCore](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java), which offers a series of useful `run(...)` overloads. Call `JUnitCore.addListener` with a [RunListener](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.java) implementation and you should be able to get the notifications you need.

Note that the total number of test cases pending may not be easy to get ahead of time; the test count is available as part of the [Description](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/Description.java#L210) object but by default JUnit doesn't seem to create all the runners and Descriptions until immediately before their run.